# loading configuration file in clojure as data structure

Tags: configuration, properties, clojure

Is there a reader function in clojure to parse clojure data structure? My use case is to read configuration properties files and one value for a property should be a list. I'd like to be able to write this as:

file.properties:

```
property1 = ["value1" "value2"]
```

and in clojure:

```
(load-props "file.properties")
```

and get a map with value {property1, ["value1" "value2"]

Right now,m I'm doing the following, with the same input file "file.properties":

```
(defn load-props [filename]
    (let [io (java.io.FileInputStream. filename)
        prop (java.util.Properties.)]
    (.load prop io)
    (into {} prop)))

;; returns:
;; {"property1" "[\"valu1\", \"valu2\"]"}
(load-props "file.properties")
```

But I cannot get a way to parse the result to a clojure's vector. I'm basically looking for something like Erlang's file:consult/1 function. Any idea how to do this?

Comment: Jonas' answer is also a good option if you're not set on a properties file.

Comment: Korny's  answer  is  the  best  one  here in 2013.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

`java.util.Properties` implements `Map` so this can be done very easily without manually parsing properties files:

```
(require 'clojure.java.io)
(defn load-props
  [file-name]
  (with-open [^java.io.Reader reader (clojure.java.io/reader file-name)] 
    (let [props (java.util.Properties.)]
      (.load props reader)
      (into {} (for [[k v] props] [(keyword k) (read-string v)])))))

(load-props "test.properties")
;=> {:property3 {:foo 100, :bar :test}, :property2 99.9, :property1 ["foo" "bar"]}
```

In particular, properties files are more complicated than you think (comments, escaping, etc, etc) and `java.util.Properties` is very good at loading them.

Comment: A little bit simplified version:  (into {} props)

Comment: You don't need to do all this with a little library called propertyid (https://github.com/michaelklishin/propertied)

Answer (score 45):

If you want to read java-style properties files, look at Dave Ray's answer - though properties files have many limitations.

If you are using Clojure 1.5 or later, I suggest you use [edn](https://github.com/edn-format/edn), the extensible data notation used in Datomic - it's basically clojure data structures, with no arbitrary code execution, and the ability to add tags for things like instances or arbitrary types.

The simplest way to use it is via [read-string](http://clojure.github.io/clojure/clojure.edn-api.html#clojure.edn/read-string) and [slurp](http://clojure.github.io/clojure/clojure.core-api.html#clojure.core/slurp):

```
(require 'clojure.edn)
(clojure.edn/read-string (slurp "filename.edn"))
```

That's it.  Note that read-string only reads a single variable, so you should set up your configuration as a map:

```
{ :property1 ["value1" "value2"] }
```

Then:

```
(require 'clojure.edn)
(def config (clojure.edn/read-string (slurp "config.edn")))
(println (:property1 config))
```

returns

```
["value1" "value2"]
```

Answer (score 25):

> Is there a reader function in clojure to parse clojure data structure?

Yes. It's called [`read`](http://clojure.github.com/clojure/clojure.core-api.html#clojure.core/read). You can also use it to read configuration data.

A file `props.clj` containing

```
{:property1 ["value1" 2]
 :property2 {:some "key"}}
```

can be read like this:

```
(ns somens.core
  (:require [clojure.java.io :as io])
  (:import [java.io PushbackReader]))

(def conf (with-open [r (io/reader "props.clj")]
            (read (PushbackReader. r))))
```

When reading untrusted sources it might be a good idea to turn of [`*read-eval*`](http://clojure.github.com/clojure/clojure.core-api.html#clojure.core/*read-eval*):

```
(def conf (binding [*read-eval* false]
            (with-open [r (io/reader "props.clj")]
              (read (PushbackReader. r)))))
```

For writing configuration data back to a file you should look at print functions such as [`pr`](http://clojure.github.com/clojure/clojure.core-api.html#clojure.core/pr) and friends.

Comment: Note that the file is never closed in your code. Use `with-open`.

Comment: Note that since clojure 1.5 you should use [clojure.edn/read](http://clojure.github.io/clojure/clojure.edn-api.html#clojure.edn/read) as read can execute arbitrary code, and [edn](https://github.com/edn-format/edn) is designed to be safe and portable.

Comment: Oh, and you can just use (read (slurp "props.clj")) - using a reader makes sense if you are reading large amounts of data, but is overkill for a simple config file.

Answer (score 3):

contrib has functions for reading writing properties,

http://richhickey.github.com/clojure-contrib/java-utils-api.html#clojure.contrib.java-utils/as-properties

If this is for your own consumption then I would suggest reading/writing clojure data structures you can just print them to disk and read them.

Comment: I don't have java-utils contrib package installed in my machine. Will test this later.

Comment: Clojure's API documentation has moved to http://clojure.github.com/clojure, and clojure-contrib has been deprecated/moved out into separate libraries under that same github account.

Answer (score 0):

```
(use '[clojure.contrib.duck-streams :only (read-lines)])
(import '(java.io StringReader PushbackReader))

(defn propline->map [line] ;;property1 = ["value1" "value2"] -> { :property1  ["value1" "value2"] }
  (let [[key-str value-str] (seq (.split line "="))
        key (keyword (.trim key-str))
        value (read (PushbackReader. (StringReader. value-str)))]
        { key value } ))

(defn load-props [filename]
  (reduce into (map propline->map (read-lines filename))))
```

**DEMO**

```
user=> (def prop (load-props "file.properties"))
#'user/prop
user=> (prop :property1)
["value1" "value2"]
user=> ((prop :property1) 1)
"value2"
```

**UPDATE**

```
(defn non-blank?   [line] (if (re-find #"\S" line) true false))
(defn non-comment? [line] (if (re-find #"^\s*\#" line) false true))

(defn load-props [filename]
  (reduce into (map propline->map (filter #(and (non-blank? %)(non-comment? %)) (read-lines filename)))))
```

Comment: Great, this is exactly what I needed. I've done changes so that propline->map function avoids comments. The updated version is below     (defn propline->map [line]
  (let [[key-str value-str] (seq (.split line "="))
        key (keyword (.trim key-str))
        value (read (PushbackReader. (StringReader. value-str)))
        comment? (.startsWith key-str "#")]
    (if (not comment?) { key value }) ))`

Comment: If you exclude the comment line that filter might be better in load-props.

Comment: Two things: 1) `Properties` already knows how to parse these files correctly. No need to partially reimplement that functionality. 2) duck-streams is deprecated. You want `clojure.java.io/reader` and `clojure.core/line-seq`.

Comment: 1)Yes. ex)(def v (read (PushbackReader. (StringReader. "[\"valu1\", \"valu2\"]")))). 2)Well I do not. I dont know deprecated.But,Can be replaced if necessary.

Comment: http://blog.darevay.com/2010/10/remedial-clojure-duck-streams-let-style-and-pronunciation/

Comment: Hi. It's true that monolithic `clojure.contrib` is full of useful functions (many of which now exist in core) and you're free to keep using them. But, it's also deprecated, and every new answer, blog post, etc that promotes it creates problems for unwitting Clojure newcomers as well as those in the Clojure community that are trying to move contrib forward. I'll update that blog post to say this even more forcefully than it already does. Cheers, Dave

Comment: That's right, your code more better. Simple and very good. I push upvote yours.