# clojure behavior of def

Tags: clojure, leiningen

I have a lein project (using cascalog--but that's not particularly important). I'm trying to externalize properties like paths to files, so I end up with code that looks something like this:

```
(defn output-tap [path] (hfs-textline (str (get-prop :output-path-prefix) path) :sinkmode :replace))

(def some-cascalog-query 
    (<- [?f1 ?f2 ?f3] 
        ((output-tap (get-prop :output-path)) ?line)
        (tab-split ?line :> ?f1 ?f2 ?f3)))
```

In the example above, assume the function `get-prop` exists; it's just using standard java to read a property value (based off this example: [loading configuration file in clojure as data structure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7777882/loading-configuration-file-in-clojure-as-data-structure)).

Now I have a main method that loads the property values, e.g. something like:

```
(defn -main [& args] (do (load-props (first args)) (do-cascalog-stuff)))
```

But when I `lein uberjar` I get a compile time error saying:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not create a Path from an empty string
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path.checkPathArg(Path.java:82)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path.<init>(Path.java:90)
at cascading.tap.hadoop.Hfs.getPath(Hfs.java:343)
```

Are defs always compile time evaluated (rather than runtime evaluated)? Or am I misunderstanding this error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, you want the property lookup to occur at run-time? Then yes, you'll need to define `some-cascalog-query` as a function or macro. A bare `def` causes the expression to be evaluated when the code is loaded, not when the var is dereferenced.

This can be illustrated pretty simply in the REPL:

```
user=> (def foo (do (println "Hello, world!") 1))
Hello, world!
#'user/foo
user=> foo
1
```

From the [documentation](http://clojure.org/special_forms) (emphasis mine):

> **(def symbol init?)**
>
> Creates and interns or locates a global var with the name of symbol and a namespace of the value of the current namespace (*ns*). *If init is supplied, it is evaluated, and the root binding of the var is set to the resulting value.*

Answer (score 0):

that error looks like `(get-prop :output-path)` `(get-prop :output-path-prefix)` are is returning nothing which is getting wrapped into an empty string by `str`. perhaps the property is not being found?

does get-prop work as expected?

your understanding of defs is correct, they are are compile time, not (usually) runtime.