# Any library for Java properties files in *new* contrib?

Tags: clojure, properties-file, clojure-contrib

In the old monolithic clojure-contrib there were `java-utils` and `properties` namespaces with a few handy functions, like `read-properties` which parsed a Java properties file into a Clojure map.

Is there an equivalent of these namespaces in the new contrib?

I know that it is easy to write (i.e. copy-paste) [the function](https://github.com/richhickey/clojure-contrib/blob/a1c66df5287776b4397cf3929a5f498fbb34ea32/src/main/clojure/clojure/contrib/java_utils.clj#L162) and I'll probably do it anyway, but if it's already somewhere I'd rather not duplicate code.

Comment: I am a little confused. Do you need a way easy read property files in Java?

Comment: @Mohayemin: No, I want to read a Java-style property file in Clojure as a Clojure-native map.

Comment: Oh, I am sorry. Then its not my play :)

Comment: Worth checking out this question:

 - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7777882/loading-configuration-file-in-clojure-as-data-structure

Comment: @mikera: Thanks, I didn't see that one. I ended up with a similar function - with keywordized keys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The java_utils library never made it, but check out [propertea](https://github.com/jaycfields/propertea).  I think it'll do what you want.